# How do I create a dialog box when it is being created in a separate dart file that isn't tied to the widget tree?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get away from [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) (lol) and focus on building my flutter app using the native `Navigator`. My `main.dart` sets `wrapper.dart` as the home page. In `wrapper`, it returns either `home.dart` or `login.dart`, depending on the value of a global variable in a provider class called `GlobalsProvider`.

If login is successful, `GlobalsProvider` runs a function called `startLoginStream`. This starts a `timer` object that runs every 5 seconds and calls a function to check the login state on a remote SQL Server instance. If the user is remotely logged out, this timer function will notice that and log the user out + show them a dialog box saying that they have been logged out remotely.

Before, I was using the Get package to do this, but I want to see if this can be done natively. However, I don't know how to handle this. I know that a dialog box requires `BuildContext`, but if my timer function is called once from `GlobalsProvider`, which can't see the widget tree, then what would I need to modify to make this work? What is the recommended practice here? Below is some relevant code. I won't paste too much to keep it light, but I can answer any questions about other stuff in the app.

**main.dart:**

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => GlobalsProvider(),
      child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp.router(
          title: 'myApp',
          routerConfig: router,
        );
      })
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SafeArea(
        child: Wrapper()
    );
  }
}
```

**wrapper.dart:**

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
      if (value.loggedIn == true) {
        return const Forms();
      } else {
        return const Login();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared navigator key to manage the navigation without a context.

```
class NavigationService {
    static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

    static final NavigationService _navigationService = NavigationService._internal();

    factory NavigationService() {
        return _navigationService;
    }

    NavigationService._internal();

    dynamic routeTo(String route, {dynamic arguments}) {

        return navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(route, arguments: arguments);
    }

    dynamic pop() {
        return navigatorKey.currentState?.pop();
    }
}
```

In your `main.dart`

```
return MaterialApp(
    navigatorKey: NavigationService().navigatorKey,
    home: const LoginScreen(),
);
```

You can send the user to the login screen using `NavigationService().routeTo("login-screen")` and then validate to show the dialog there, would be easier because of the buildContext.
I don't know the better approach for this kind of situation, but hope it helps.

Comment: I'm already using Go Router, which requires me to use `MaterialApp.router` and doesn't have navigatorKey as a parameter. How do I accomplish this using Go Router?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice this part, i was reading and tested this Go Router, for what i saw you can use the same `router` var that you used in the `MaterialApp .Router` to make a navigation without a context, idk where you did set your router configuration, but if you use the same reference and do a `router.push(route)` you will be fine.
In my test, i just added the `GoRouter` config to the `NavigationService` class and got it from there to setup the `MaterialApp.router` and also to navigate among the screens